# Rails newb - Can you help me with my models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, models

First question here and new to Ruby, so take it easy on me.  I've attempted to diagram some models + associations for my first app before I get started to make sure I'm comprehending fundamental concepts to build on.

[image]

Are my models correct for what I'm trying to accomplish?
If not, could someone offer up some suggestions or recommendations?
Is there an easier way to do what I'm trying to do?
From a workflow perspective, is this an efficient way for a beginner to get started in the absence of solid syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: Customers: It it has _many_ quote_requests, why do you reference one quote via quote_request_id? Same applies to quote_id in providers. I think you can 'see' it, as you have two x two models with references in both directions (customers/quote_requests) and (providers/quotes)

Comment: Nippey - Thanks for your feedback...I understand your question but don't quite know how to answer it.  

In the place of the singular "quote_request_id" in customers, what should I change it to, or how do I show the "many" association?

Would it be ok to drop the "quote_request_id" and "quote_id" from the customers/providers models?

Comment: Well, I would drop the `quote_request_id` and the `quote_id` if I understood it right as you look for quote requests by selecting those from table `quote_requests` which have the right `customer_id`. You don't need the above-mentioned id's then.

Comment: anybody answer that helpful to you then accept that answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers
  has_many :providers
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :customer_quote_requests
  has_many :quote_requests, :through => :customer_quote_requests

  has_many :customer_quotes
  has_many :quotes, :through => :customer_quotes
end

class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :provider_quotes
  has_many :quotes, :through => :provider_quotes

  has_many :provider_quote_requests
  has_many :quote_requests, :through => :provider_quote_requests

end

class QuoteRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customer_quote_requests
  has_many :customers :through => :customer_quote_requests

  has_many :provider_quote_requests
  has_many :providers, :through => :provider_quote_requests
end

class CustomerQuoteRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :quote_request
end

class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :provider_quotes
  has_many :provider, :through => :provider_quotes

  has_many :customer_quotes
  has_many :customers, :through => :customer_quotes

end

class ProviderQuote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :provider
  belongs_to :qoute
end

class ProviderQuoteRequests < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :provider
  belongs_to :quote_requests
end

class CustomerQuotes < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :quote
end
```

Comment: Dipak - Thank you!

If you have another quick second, could you share why I was off with using "has_many_and_belongs_to" here?  I'm guessing the additional models you created satisfy my intent and render it unnecessary...

Comment: Super embarrassed that I got the syntax of the association wrong...'has_and_belongs_to_many' was what I meant, not flipping it around in my head.  :o

Comment: has_many - through  is better then has_many_and_belongs_to because see this link - (1) http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many (2) http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/1/15/basic-rails-association-cardinality?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

Answer (score 0):

General Answer to my comments below your question:

If you have two tables with a `1:n` relation, you do not reference all `n` elements in you parent table. You only define to which `1` does the child table belong.

In your case:
`quote_requests` belongs to `customers`.
So you reference the customer within `quote_requests` via `customer_id`.

That is enough. This way you can have Zero, One or Many `quote_requests` belonging to a customer.

(Tell yourself the question: What use does the `quote_request_id` have if you have Zero or more than One entry? If you set it to zero then, does this reference an id or does it mean, that no element is assigned?)